# How do I restore the Windows 10 entry to Windows Boot Manager? I accidentally deleted it

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

I dual-boot with Arch Linux and was trying to do so using Windows Boot Manager because I was facing a problem with Grub. I managed to fix it in the end, but while I was still trying, I used EasyBCD to add a Grub entry to Windows Boot Manager, but when that didn't help, I tried to delete the entry I created, but for some reason, the Windows 10 entry was deleted instead, and I'm locked out of Windows now. I can still boot into Linux through Grub, which shows Arch Linux and Windows Boot Manager as options. While Windows Boot Manager shows "grub" and an entry I created called "Arch Linux" (this is the one I was trying to delete).

I tried Startup Repair from a bootable drive (Win10 ISO) but it did not help at all, because an upgrade requires me to boot the medium *from* Windows 10 (which I cannot access), and a reinstall onto my existing Windows partition was met with an error. I don't know the cause of the error because I don't know where the setup logs are.

**Is there a way to edit Windows Boot Manager in Linux (the way you'd do in BCDEDIT.exe or similar)?**

I did install EasyBCD on Linux to attempt to add a Windows 10 entry, but the program won't run. I'm even considering installing Windows 11 hoping it would add a bootloader entry, but the only way to do so without losing any data is, you guessed it, through the Windows 10 settings and not an installation medium.

Comment: Did you try using `bcdedit` from installation media? You can open a console after you enter the installation wizard. Check this: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-start-command-prompt-when-windows-doesnt-boot/

Comment: @charlesz I tried that now. I used `bcdedit` to add a bootloader entry for Windows 10, but it's unusable. I'm getting the same error that I get from the Linux options in Windows Boot Manager, which is that Windows couldn't boot.

Comment: Are you using UEFI or Legacy? I recall `bcdedit` command might be different. Also, what is the current state? Windows Boot Loader shows both Windows 10 and Arch but Windows 10 cannot boot, Arch can boot?

Comment: UEFI. Basically, in the Windows Boot Manager, none of the entries work. To boot into Arch, I exit Windows Boot Manager, so that Grub pops up instead. Arch is bootable from there.

Comment: @charlesz I tried again. This time, I formatted the EFI partition and copied boot files using `bcdboot` and I'm on Windows now. Thanks for the help. I didn't realise I could have used the commandline. Also, I'd like to add that it seems that multiple users have had this issue with EasyBCD (that is having the Windows entries removed unintentionally).

Comment: I reposted my comment as an answer. Thanks for letting me know that it works. @Troy

Answer (score 0):

(Moving my comment as answer.)

Try using `bcdedit` from installation media. You can open a console after you enter the installation wizard. Check this: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-start-command-prompt-when-windows-doesnt-boot/.

Briefly:

1. Wait for the Windows Setup to load, select the language and keyboard if you’re prompted, and then press Next. Don't click/tap on Install now. Instead, click or tap "Repair your computer" on the bottom-left corner of the wizard or press R on your keyboard.
2. You are asked to choose an option on how to continue. Choose Troubleshoot.
3. You are shown several advanced options, but only the Command Prompt option interests us: click or tap on it to get to CMD at boot.

Once in command line, use `diskpart` to assign a drive letter to the EFI partition, and run `bcdedit` according to this: https://woshub.com/how-to-repair-uefi-bootloader-in-windows-8/.

---

Update: OP says they needed to format the EFI partition before rebuilding BCD.